# Finding $A^k$ for a large $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a matrix A that I have found a matrix $P$ for such that $P^{-1}AP$ is now diagonal, is it possible to calculate $A^k$ for a large $k$?

I assume it has something to do with the fact that $(P^{-1}AP)^k=P^{-1}A^kP$, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: The following is regarding the matrix exponential, but is a good read, and may have some relevant info: http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2012/07/23/a-balancing-act-for-the-matrix-exponential/#abdda55e-1fbd-460f-856a-ae8ee6c475a5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal, finding $(P^{-1}AP)^k$ is trivial since we have to simply raise each element on the diagonal to $k$

Now, $(P^{-1}AP)^k=P^{-1}A^kP$ as you say. Let $(P^{-1}AP)^k=M$
$$\therefore M=P^{-1}A^kP$$
$$\implies PMP^{-1}=A^k$$

Comment: Thank you- makes perfect sense now!

Comment: @SujaanKunalan It should be noted, though, that this doesn't always work in terms of computing. The theory is, of course, solid (in case you can get $P^{-1}AP$ to be diagonal), but there are matrices where the [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) (the diagonalization that you've done) is numerically unstable and the above computation can produce completely wrong results when done on a computer. This almost certainly isn't the case with your matrix, but be aware that you cannot always do it.

Answer (score 2):

$P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal then 
 $$(P^{-1}AP)^k=\begin{pmatrix}
    r_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &0 \\
   0 & r_2& 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 &0 &0 & \cdots & r_n    
     \end{pmatrix}^k$$$$(P^{-1}AP)^k=P^{-1}A^kP$$ $$\Rightarrow A^k=p\begin{pmatrix}
    r_1^k & 0 & 0 & \cdots &0 \\
   0 & r_2^k& 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 &0 &0 & \cdots & r_n^k    
     \end{pmatrix}p^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming right. If $D$ is diagonal matrix, $D=diag(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$, then $D^k = diag(\lambda_1^k, \ldots, \lambda_n^k)$.